# 3D vector field

Tags: plot, 3d, gnuplot, vector-graphics

I need help plotting a vector field in 3D,
my problem is that I have a table with

```
x, y, z, Vx, Vy, Vz
```

These are the position and components of each vector, the vectors are normalized so its magnitude is one, and this is the problem because the unit cell on which my vectors are centered is a cube of side 5nm.
And from this follow that drawing a vector with magnitude 1 on a cell so small won't work.

So my question is, how can I normalize the vectors to the size of the cell if this is possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I fully understand your problem. Please provide more information, data and some code.

My guess: you want to scale the length of your vector by factor 5 (or maybe 5e-9?). Please clarify.

**Code:**

```
### scale vectors
reset session
set view equal xyz

# example data
$Data <<EOD
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7071 0.7071 0.0000
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5773 0.5773 0.5773
EOD

myFactor = 5    # or do you mean 5e-9 ???
set view 70,45

splot $Data u 1:2:3:($4*myFactor):($5*myFactor):($6*myFactor) w vectors notitle

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes this should work. Basically I have a solid, like a cube of side 1e-6 and it is divided in ccubic cell of 5e-9 and in the center of each cell there is a vector rapresenting the magnetization of that small cell, since the vector is normalized its to big for the cell and scaling it as you suggest may work. Only thing I hope that i will be seeing something clear cause as you can imagine I've got a really big number of cells!!